# How to solve error 'coordinate exceeds the valid coordinate' in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, map-service

All of the layers in map document are in wgs84. I am getting an error message in the ArcGIS server log for one specific layer (see below). I ran the analyze tool from the Map Service Publishing option and it did not pick up any errors on this layer.

How to fix the issue? Does anyone know the reason for this error?

```
<Msg time='2012-12-13T13:51:13' type='ERROR' code='103800' target='Test.MapServer' machine='server1' user='?' process='5164' thread='7384'>Texas: Layer_RK:  The specified coordinate exceeds the valid coordinate range </Msg>
```

Comment: It looks like there's a feature in "Texas: Layer_RK" that is way out of bounds. If it's possible, check the coordinates of the features for that layer?

Comment: In my experience with ArcMap, when I get that error, it is due to incorrect geometry, or features that are out in la la land. A quick check is to add your layer to ArcMap and zoom to the layer.  If most of your features are grouped in a small area and there are outliers separate from the rest with ridiculous coordinates, those need to be fixed.

Comment: @Mintx@Baltok the layer has only one feature..

Comment: One more point to add here when scale is  less than 1:800000 ArcMap does not throws an error, but beyond 8,00000 it trowse One or more layers failed to draw:

Texas:Layer_RK:  The specified coordinate exceeds the valid coordinate range

Comment: Are the layers in the map document in GCS WGS84 or in WGS84 Web Mercator? Also make sure the Extent in your data frame is valid.

Comment: Another test is to export your data and see if that fixes any geometry problems. You can also use another software package to export the data from and then bring it back into ArcMap. Sorry we can't help more.

Comment: If this is still an issue would you be able to edit your question to include responses to the questions that people have asked in Comments.  While there are still no Answers is an ideal time to heavily revise your Question to try and elicit an Answer.  I think you should also include your ArcGIS version number(s).